# Working locally but not on production UnsatisfiedDependencyException creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-security

The application locally is working properly, but after deployment gets the error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:
>
> Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name '**webSecurityConfiguration**': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field '**userDetailsService**'; nested
> exception

Last week I deployed an older version of the **same application** and application was working properly. How can I fix it?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private EntryPointUnauthorizedHandler unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired//package org.springframework.security.core.userdetails;
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

I use spring boot and war with `providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'`, on server Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 and java: 1.8.0_11-b12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Autowired//
 private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

[package org.springframework.security.core.userdetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/package-summary.html) in my case, the problem was with the database and the code itself was correct and did not require changes